# Oracle DB link is not working

Tags: oracle, ssh, vpn, portforwarding, dblink

We have 2 Oracle db. Let's say A & B.

Need to create DB link from A to B.

A is cloud DB which installed in private network, through SSH and local port forward we can access A.

B is also installed in private network, through VPN we can access B.

Both A and B DB's cannot access directly.

I created DB link from A to B. But it is not working, got below error

```
ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred
12170. 00000 -  "TNS:Connect timeout occurred"
*Cause:    The server shut down because connection establishment or
           communication with a client failed to complete within the allotted time
           interval. This may be a result of network or system delays; or this may
           indicate that a malicious client is trying to cause a Denial of Service
           attack on the server.
*Action:   If the error occurred because of a slow network or system,
           reconfigure one or all of the parameters SQLNET.INBOUND_CONNECT_TIMEOUT,
           SQLNET.SEND_TIMEOUT, SQLNET.RECV_TIMEOUT in sqlnet.ora to larger values.
           If a malicious client is suspected, use the address in sqlnet.log to
           identify the source and restrict access. Note that logged addresses may
           not be reliable as they can be forged (e.g. in TCP/IP).
```

I searched on internet and tried many times.

Some one advice me how to create DB link from A to B.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

"TNS:Connect timeout occurred" as the name suggests means we could not get from "A" to "B" for any possible network reason (firewall, physical network, etc).

Try tackling it this way. Log on to server A, run tnsping/sqlplus from that machine to attempt a connection to B.  That might involve setting up wallets, sqlnet.ora, tnsnames.ora etc, as well as potentially getting network people involved depending on firewalls etc.

But if you can get a connection initiated from server A to B, then only at this point will you be able to get a database link from A to B.  (And obviously the same applies for getting data *back* from B to A).